# Question about Fulton's Algebraic Curves Exercise 8.13

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Hi I prove the first part of this problem but I don't know how to show the last part,

**8.13.** Suppose $l(D) >0 $, and let $f\ne 0$, $f\in l(D)$. Show that $f \notin L(D- P)$ for all but a finite number of $P$. So $l(D- P)=l(D)-1 $ for all but a finite number of $P$.

I don't understand how to get $l(D-P) = l(D) -1$,

**Steps**

The inequality that is notable is the following from what we prove: there exists an $ f$ in $L(D)/L(D-P)$,
Furthermore, it is not difficult to show that if f is in $L(D-P)$ it is in $L(D)$ then we will have that $l(D-P) < l(D)$ then $l(D-P) \le l(D) -1$ but how could I show the other inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From proposition $3$ in the same chapter of the exercise you know:
$l(D)-l(D-P)\leq deg(D-(D-P))=1$.

Comment: It's true, thank you very much :3